# What is a trusted notebook in DSX?

Tags: data-science-experience

What is a trusted notebook in DSX?   What difference between a trusted and untrusted notebook?

The on-line documentation is not clear on this.

Comment: This question is better suited for the DSX support channel. Have you tried that?

Comment: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/security.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run all notebook cells in the Apache Spark service to ensure that the notebook is considered trusted by the service.

When you open a notebook, the Apache Spark service verifies the signature of the notebook. If the signature is not valid, the notebook is considered untrusted, and the javascript and HTML output will not be displayed. You must rerun all notebook cells to generate a new signature in the notebook metadata, and the notebook will be considered trusted.

More info here: https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/trusted-notebooks.html?context=analytics